Is there a version of the Crystal Report Runtime which works on Tomcat 10.1 and Java 21?
I am in the process of upgrading our core application to run on updated libraries - specifically the latest LTS Java version (OpenJDK 21) along with Tomcat 10.1 - which includes the Jakarta library migration.
Part of our application contains an integration with Crystal Reports for our reporting - and we host the Crystal Report Runtime as part of this on the same Tomcat instance.
We are currently using the 2020 runtime, but after having a look at the options available, it seems all are reliant on javax classes (which are not available in the newer versions of Java given the Jakarta migration changes).
I have tried several versions of the Crystal Report Viewer - such as the 2020 build, and the latest runtime included in Crystal Report For Eclipse - both have the same errors about javax classes not being present - indicating that the Crystal Report Runtime seems to be still relying on Java 8 classes (javax.servlet in particular).
Downloads were from here: https://origin.softwaredownloads.sap.com/public/site/index.html
Are there any versions of the Crystal Reports Runtime which work on the latest LTS builds of Java, given it's EOL coming in the next few years?
Happy to switch runtimes if there is one released, it is quite possible I missed one if it exists - but any advice would be greatly appreciated.

The javax to jakarta change is unrelated to the Java upgrade; it is related to you switching from Tomcat 9 or older (i.e. Java EE / Jakarta EE 8 or older)  to Tomcat 10 or newer (i.e. Jakarta EE 9 or newer). In any case, Crystal Reports is a commercial product, so you should contact their customer service if you can't find a version of their product or don't know if they even offer this option.
